# how to pop a div out of the hidden flow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have table with multiple columns and row that renders simple data.  The last column is the action column whose each row contain a dropdown - edit/stop functions.  On the last row, the dropdown get cuts off, and that's because the `table` element has a `overflow:hidden`.  This is need because the highlight needs to stop at the last table row.

I tried to remove the `position: relative` from the `optionSection` class but the dropdown goes to the `body`.  How can I make the dropdown pop out from where it is - as show in the picture - and not mess with the `overflow:hidden`.  Is there an alternative to this, having the dropdown to popout and stop the highlight at the last row?

Below is the html and css code.

```
<table>
 <thead>
   <th class="sortHightlight">1</th>
   <th class="sortHightlight">2</th>
   <th class="sortHightlight">3</th>
   <th class="sortHightlight">4</th>
   <th>action</th>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>..</tr>
  <tr>..</tr>
  <tr>..</tr>
  <tr>..</tr>
  <tr>..</tr>
  <tr>..</tr>
  <tr>..</tr>
  <tr>..</tr>
  <tr>..</tr>
  <tr>
   <td>..</td>
   <td>..</td>
   <td>..</td>
   <td>..</td>
   <td>
    <div class="settingWrapper">
     <div class="optionSection">
      <div class="settingWrapper">
       <div class="settingsIcon"></div>
       <div class="downIconDropdown"></div>
      </div>
     <div class="listContainer showOverlayDropdown">
      <div class="listBtn">
       <div class="upIconDropdown"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="list">
       <ul><li>Edit</li><li>Stop</li></ul>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

css

```
table {
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;}

.optionSection {
    color: #0083C6;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.optionSection .listContainer {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #BFBFBF;
    border-radius: 3px;
    top: 0;
    right: 46px;
}

.sortHighlight:hover::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #B8BABB;
  opacity: 0.15;
  left: 0;
  top: 42px;
  height: 10000px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

picture

[image]

[image: dropdown needs to pop out]

Comment: Easiest way is to not use overflow:hidden on your table, although I'm not sure what highlight you're talking about? Please clarify what you mean by highlight

Comment: is a `z-index` on the dropdown not working? or simply `position: absolute` from its parent position

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/ has some approaches, but it needs some very specific conditions to work. // What you’re on about here with the highlighting and how that requires hidden overflow, I didn’t get either.

Comment: Best way to get a useful answer is to include an [mcve] that illustrates the current condition, which would allow us to understand what you mean about the highlighting.  You _say_ below is the HTML, but in fact that _is not_ the fully rendered HTML, so we can't use it to test / understand your problem.

Comment: @TedFitzpatrick the highlight is gray color where "app" is at.  This highlight is triggered when you hover the header column.  Notice how it stops at the last row, but if I remove the `overflow:hidden`, then it will pass the last row and it's due to the height: 10000px from `sortHighlight:hover::after` css  - I just added it.  I could remove the `overflow`, but how can I make the highlight stop at the last row.   Number of rows are not fixed, so it can be any numbers

Comment: See my comment above.  You'd save us all time and frustration with an [mcve]

Comment: If I was making this I'd likely use JS or SASS for the effect, style the relevant td's and do away with the super-tall ::after element. Currently CSS doesn't support this (style other non-descendent/non-sibling elements when an arbitrary element is hovered). Pure CSS, you could get creative with a divs following the table that would hide the overflowing portion of the highlight element. Perhaps another div would wrap the table and these new "hider" divs to maintain desired height.